Converting an integral to hypergeometric function
I have encountered an integral as follows $$\int_{0}^{1}{\left(k^{2}x^{2}-k^{2}x+m_{2}^{2}+m_{1}^{2}x-m_{2}^{2}x   \right)^{\frac{d-4}{2}}}dx$$ Any suggestion how to convert it into a hypergeometric function?

I have tried to take (1-x) and x out of the integrand to match it with the standard integral form for hypergeometric function. It turns out to be not working. Definitely I am missing out something.

$$ (k^{2}x^{2}-(k^{2}-m_{1}^{2}+m_{2}^{2})x+m_{2}^{2})^{\frac{d-4}{2}}
=(m_{2}^{2})^{\frac{d-4}{2}}(\frac{k^{2}}{m_{2}^{2}}x^{2}-(\frac{k^{2}-m_{1}^{2}+m_{2}^{2}}{m_{2}^{2}})x+1)^{\frac{d-4}{2}} $$

Hints
Don't you think that it would be simpler to change notations ?
Let
$$a=k^2 \qquad b=-(k^2+m_2-m_1^2) \qquad c=m_2^2 \qquad k=\frac {d-4}2$$ to make
$$I=\int(ax^2+bx+c)^k\, dx=k\int \Big((x-\alpha)(x-\beta)\Big)^k\,dx$$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the quadratic.
Now, let
$$x=\alpha+(\alpha-\beta)\,t\quad \implies \quad I=k\, (\alpha -\beta )^{2 k+1}\int t^k (t+1)^k\,dt$$
then
$$t=u-\frac 12\quad \implies \quad I=\frac{k \,(\alpha -\beta )^{2 k+1}}{4^k}\int (4u^2-1)^k \,du$$
which you could continue with $u=\frac 14 \cosh(v)$ and soforthe.
which is more than simple.
Finish the work, go back to $x$ and use the bounds.
